# How to commit INSERT INTO if I don't have all the values

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using Psycopg2 in Python in order to insert data to a PostgreSQL summary table. The data I am trying to insert is data that I get from hundreds of CSV files. I know how to get the data that I need and I already have code that does it. The problem is that in some CSV files there are certain values that don't exist.

for example:
file #1:

```
XBT:1
ABC:2
ABD:3
...
...
```

file #2:

```
ABC:4
ABD:5
...
...
```

In this case, I am using a dictionary in order to insert the data later to the table.
So first I have a function that creates the dictionary. In this case, the first dictionary will look like this:

```
{'XBT':1,'ABC':2,'ABD':3}
```

and the second will look like this:

```
{'ABC':4,'ABD':5}
```

The problem will be at the INSERT INTO command. I have a function that inserts the data to the table and looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
summary(XBT,ABC,ABD)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
```

When the loop will try to go through the second file, I will get an error because the dictionary will not have the 'XBT' value.
The solution I am looking for is that If the dictionary is missing a value, the INSERT INTO function still adds a new row to the table, that will be without the missing value. Create INSERT INTO function for each scenario isn't possible because there are more than 100 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to turn the keys in your dictionary into a `%s` as well and build the string as you go along and build the corresponding array as well. Then you can combine everything and execute the statement.

```
key_str = ''
val_string = ''
key_arr = []
val_arr = []
for key, value in your_dict.iteritems():
    key_str += "%s,"
    val_str += "%s,"
    key_arr.append(key)
    val_arr.append(value)
# Then do some string manipulation
command = "INSERT INTO summary({keys}) VALUES ({values})".format(keys=key_str[:1], values = val_str[:1])
# and combine your arrays
substitutions = key_arr + val_arr
# Then execute the command
cursor.execute(command, substitutions)
# Continue with whatever you were going for.
```